# Rails app with one set of models, but two server processes (e.g. users and admin sections are separate)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose that you wanted to create two apps, both on Rails, but they share the same set of models. I'm certain I could 'hack' something together, that would probably work, but I'm curious what the best approach is.

Oh, and if you're curious about motivation: I want to freely restart the admin processes without disturbing the user processes. Also there is a bit of extra security not sharing the same session.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a gem or engine with your models in the lib directory.  Then they could easily be used by more than one Rails app.  Google "rails engines" and you should get some ideas.  If all you're doing is models though, a fullblown engine may be overkill and you can get by with a simple gem.

Comment: So I should gemify all my models, keeping them as a separate project, and pull from it regularly?

Comment: You could, but that might be overkill.  If you check the docs for the Gemspec file, you can reference a gem from a local directory so you wouldn't need to publish it or put it on github or anything.  Kind of like an oldschool C include.